# How to share my location from flutter app to whatsapp number?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, whatsapp, flutter-dependencies

I have a function that shared data to whatsapp number, but when sending a google location it`s not working.

when printing the URL that I get at this function:
`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=9.5191017,8.1450133`

but I see that in WhatsApp look like:
`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1`

my code :

```
_launchURL() async {
    var phonenumber = numberphone.substring(1,10);
    var url = 'https://wa.me/+972$phonenumber?text=$textToSend';
    print(url);
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url);
    } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
}
```

my code that called the _launchURL()

```
onPressed: () async{
    Position position = await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    textToSend='https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}'.toString() ;   
    _launchURL();
}
```

any one can help me how to share location in whatsapp app using flutter ?
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this link it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947937/flutter-open-whatsapp-with-text-message

Comment: Its not help , I tried that before

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue using the code below

```
final maps = Uri.https("google.com", "/maps/search/", { "api=1&query": "$lat,$lng" });
```

Comment: So  you then put maps.toString() as textToSend? Is it possible to have a longer message, like text: "Hey my location is: \n ${maps.toString()}"

Comment: Hi, I don't send it with .toString, I create a variable to send a text, like the code below:
    
    String _messageMotoBoy = "Estabelecimento: $_establishment \n\n"
      "Bairro: $nbHood \n"
      "Comp: $comp \n"
      "Ref: $ref \n"
      "Cidade: $cityUf \n\n\n"
      "Cobrar do Cliente: R\$ $total \n\n"
      "Forma de pagamento\n"
      "$_methodPayment"      
      "Localização da entrega \n\n"
      "$waze \n\n"
      "$maps";

var whatsappUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=+55${driver.phone}&text=$_messageMotoBoy";